# Mathematically preserve resonance?

Tags: fourier-transform

First of all, please forgive me for not providing any context, as I cannot.

I wondered: 
Suppose there are two functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, each contains a few discrete frequencies.

So, their Fourier transform $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are just some spikes.

The two functions may have some common frequencies $f_1, f_2,...,f_k$.

Then, is there a certain mathematical way(maybe a transform) to produce a new $a(x)$, $a’(x)$, such that any non-common frequencies are removed from $a(x)$, while the common frequencies remain present with amplitude unchanged?

In short, is there a way to mathematically preserve only the resonance part?

Comment: Why, get a product of their Fourier transforms, it will have spikes just where you need them. Normalize the spikes, multiply the result by A(x) and transform it back.

Comment: You could convolve them in the time domain.  If you have the FFTs already, @IvanNeretin 's suggestion is better.  You're essentially performing matched filtering.